# Determining outliers

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, outliers

I have a data set containing 12 concentrations with 8 absorbance readings each. From this I did linear regression of three consecutive concentrations and their absorbances and got 10 slopes. I am trying to determine outliers from the ten slopes in order to have a concentration range that yields a linear relationship. What method should I use to get the outliers? I have tried ANOVA with Tukey post hoc, but honestly I might be using it wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you get 10 from 12 and 8, and how are you using ANOVA?

Comment: For example concentration 1-3 are used to get Slope 1 and concentrations 2-4 are used to get Slope 2, concentration 3-5 are used to get Slope 3, and so on. For each concentration 8 readings are taken. I grouped the absorbances used for each slope calculation and just ran anova on excel but this was based on a different paper. It doesn't necessarily mean ANOVA has to be used. I just need a good way to determine outliers.

Comment: How do you use those concentrations to get a slope? You’re calling it linear regression; what exactly did you do?

Comment: Concentration on x axis, absorbance on y axis. Linear regression on the resulting points results to get slope.

Comment: Why not combine all of the data and get one regression equation that gives you one slope? I get what you’re trying to do by averaging over many observations, but that happens inside the calculation of the regression equation.

Comment: There is a range of concentration that will yield a linear relationship. I am trying to identify the specific range and not use the full concentration gradient.

Comment: Ok so you want to know the point at which the relationship levels off (or somehow changes from linear)?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wanted to remove some of the outlier slopes that yield a non linear relationship for the concentration range.

Comment: You should probably fit a logistic distribution to the data and use ascending limb for your estimates

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?